# VPN Server Address with path

Tags: vpn

My VPN provider offers different profiles to connect to by putting in a path after the server address.  I'm able to do this with the Cisco AnyConnect client but using the native VPN I get an error saying the VPN server could not be found.

[image]

Is there a way to setup the native VPN connection to accept/use a server address in the format of `myvpnserver.com/profile1`?

Comment: Who's the VPN provider?  How profiles are handled is not a universal thing so we'll need details about who the provider is so we can see what their service is looking for.  It's also *very* helpful to provide base details like macOS version and your Mac model.  Please [edit] the original question with the details.

Comment: I can't disclose the provider and I might be sending the describing what I'm looking for incorrectly.  All I'm looking for is based on OSx 10.15.4 does the native OSx VPN setup only allow the Host name only?  Or is there a way to tell the profile to connect to the Host on a path?